# How can I schedule my tests in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, scheduled-tasks

I started with tests in general and with JMeter in particular. I would like to schedule the launch of my scenarios every five minutes.

There is a startup configuration tab in my group of units, in which I can set the date and time.

However, whenever I try to set the date and time, those settings always get overridden with another date. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Stick to English, please. Ecris ta question en anglais, s'il te plait.

Answer (score 0):

To Schedule JMeter Scripts you can use crontab for linux and for windows you can use at.exe.